# Highlight Non-breaking spaces in HTML page or WordPress editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, wordpress, editor

While editing in WordPress, I sometimes use non-breaking spaces in headers so that words stay together. When I save, the non-breaking spaces are there, but they look like normal spaces, so I can't see them. 
Also, WordPress creates non-breaking spaces when I type in the body of my post, which I have to remove somehow.

I thought it'd be easy to create a bookmarklet that uses jQuery to highlight non-breaking spaces in a web page or the editor. However, I'm no good with regular expressions, or maybe there's something else I'm doing wrong. Here's the jQuery code:

```
    $('p').html($('p').html().replace(/ [\u00a0\u1680\u180e\u2000-\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000]/g, '<span class="red">&nbsp;</span>'));
```

Here's a jFiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/y18e0c1w/

========

Maraca helped me out here (see below). I created the bookmarklet with his code, and added a white-space:nowrap to the span so that you can still see the highlight if it’s at the end of a line. Here it is:

```
javascript:function%20escapeRegExp(e){return%20e.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()\]\[\/\\])/g,"\\$1")}function%20replaceAll(e){return%20e.string.replace(new%20RegExp(escapeRegExp(e.search),"g"),e.replace)}jQuery("body").html(replaceAll({string:jQuery("body").html(),search:"&nbsp;",replace:'<u%20style="background:#FF0;white-space:nowrap">%20</u>'}));
```

Remember, it relies on jQuery already being loaded on the page. It doesn't play nice with the WordPress backend, but it works on the frontend and that's good for me right now. Hope someone else finds this useful too.

Comment: I updated my solution, this is it right? if not let me know. what's missing

Comment: Hi Maraca, that's great! It works well in the fiddle. However, when I apply it to my formatted page (I just pasted into the console) it places the contents of the first <p> into every consecutive </p>.

Comment: Also, do you know a simple way to go through more than just the p tags? I copied the function and that works, but I'd have to do it for multiple headers. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y18e0c1w/6/)

Comment: yes, you can define a set of tags and then process them one by one in a loop, it can get pretty complicated if you really want a generalized solution.

Comment: That is great — whole body suits my purposes perfectly. I minified and URL encoded the spaces for the bookmarklet — works like a charm. Here is the code: `javascript:function%20escapeRegExp(e){return%20e.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()\]\[\/\\])/g,"\\$1")}function%20replaceAll(e){return%20e.string.replace(new%20RegExp(escapeRegExp(e.search),"g"),e.replace)}jQuery("body").html(replaceAll({string:jQuery("body").html(),search:"&nbsp;",replace:'<u%20style="background:#FF0">%20</u>'}));`

Comment: Great, you can include it at the bottom of your question for others to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it: https://jsfiddle.net/y18e0c1w/2/

```
function escapeRegExp(s) {
    return s.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()\]\[\/\\])/g, '\\$1');   
}

function replaceAll(p) {
 return p['string'].replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(p['search']), 'g'), p['replace']);   
}

$('p').html(
    replaceAll({
        string: $('p').html(),
        search: '&nbsp;',
        replace: '<span class="red"> </span>'
    })
);
```

The first two functions are just helper functions. Then I replace `&nbsp;` by a span, that's it.

Note that I used a normal space in the span, because then there is no problem with repeated execution. Otherwise you would wrap the `&nbsp;` with span tags each exection.

The quick and dirty solution for the whole body: https://jsfiddle.net/y18e0c1w/7/